# Reverse polish notation in Haskell that computes inputs without spaces between characters

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, postfix-notation

I'm trying to write a program that takes a string input and return the value after computing the input using polish notation. Here is my code, the problem is that I need to calculate for every input for example  for input `3 4 5 * -` the result is -17, but for the input `345*-` I got `Exception: Prelude.read: no parse`

Here is my code:

```
rpcalc :: String -> Float
chunksOf :: Int -> [e] -> [[e]]
chunksOf n [] = []

rpcalc = head .foldl foldingFunction [] . words  
where   foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys  
  foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys  
  foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "-" = (y - x):ys
  foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "/" = (y / x):ys
  foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "^" = (y ** x):ys
  foldingFunction (x:xs) "ln" = log  x:xs
  foldingFunction xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

Thank you for help guys, I'm new to functional programming and is harder then I thought. *Note: I'm not using chunksOf in anyway.

Comment: Consider the result of `words "3 4 5 * -"` vs the result of `words "345*-"`.

Comment: For the first input there are separate chars and for the second input is the entire string. So i should use another function to split the string?

Comment: Your desired syntax is slightly less than trivial, so you need a more sophisticated tokenizer than `words`. If you didn't have `ln` (i.e. if every lexeme was a single character) then you could use `filter (/= ' ')`. Try writing a primitive recursive function of type `String -> [String]` which handles your desired notation; you might be interested in [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:stripPrefix) function (also `dropWhile (/= ' ')` could be useful)

Comment: I tried and failed to implement a function that splits a string into characters. Is someone can provide an example that will be wonderful.

Comment: What if I *want* to operate on the number 345, rather than the numbers 3, 4, and 5?

Comment: Well, what I`m trying to do accept only numbers who are less or equal to 9.